# Laravel pagination links onEachSide() not working on Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Is there a way to make this work?

```
{{ $records->onEachSide(2) }}
```

Where you will only have two links on each side? It shows 5 links on each side - 2 on each side with a ... followed by another two. There is little documentation officially for this. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Did you try different values? That looks correct to me; 2 on each side (6 and 7, 9 and 10), the `...` and the first/last couple pages, and the arrows.

Comment: If this doesn't fit your needs, you can create your own pagination view as per the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view.